# How to parse word using grok

Tags: regex, parsing, grok

I am very new in grok syntax. I have lines:

```
/app-name/version/code_suffix/sync
```

for example:

```
/my-app/v1/O03_ABCD/sync
/my-app/v1/O04/sync
```

and I need to parse code which always consist from 3 characters. I tried something using:

```
http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match
```

but with no success

Comment: *I need to parse code which always consist from 3 characters* not clear!

Comment: @revo not very explicit, but he defines "code" in his format above.

Comment: I saw that *code* earlier but a need to *parse it* with a regular expression... I don't get it. @Aaron

Comment: @revo I've assumed that OP had a file full of such lines and wanted to retrieve the codes from this. I realize that's a big assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match each part of your format and put it in a named capturing group :

```
/(?<appName>[^/]*)/(?<version>[^/]*)/(?<code>[^\W_]{3})(?:_(?<suffix>[^/]*))?/sync
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/WEmC7O/3), and it also works on grokConstructor.

Comment: Where this *...which always consist from 3 characters* is applied in your regex?

Comment: @revo I felt like it wasn't important, but I agree my answer was too hasty and we may need more info from OP. I've added the 3 characters requirement, but we probably still need to know what other lines can appear in the log in order to make sure not to match them

Comment: OP isn't clear to me and not you either. In the same boat.

Comment: It does work, but I'd use `(?<code>[^\W_]{3})` to only match 3 letters or digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the suggestion, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, you mistaken. I didn't say you are not clear. I said OP is not clear to both of us.

Comment: @revo oh, sorry I misunderstood you.